# Nginx reverse proxy works for HTTPS but not for HTTP

Tags: nginx

I am very new to nginx and trying to use it as a reverse proxy for my apache/php application that is behind internal load balancer with IP : 10.0.1.4 
I am trying to redirect traffic that comes to my NGINX reverse proxy to the internal load balancer's IP.

When i use HTTPS configuration in proxy.conf , it works fine with self signed cert errors in the browser which is expected.

but when I use NON SSL version of proxy.conf and try to hit nginx reverse proxy on port 80, it does not redirect to my application URL.

following are the contents of my file. Please help me if you can. i spent a lot of time before posting the issue here. i could not get it working.

My environment : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo) on Azure 
nginx version: nginx/1.15.5 
Nginx.Service : Active and Running

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX.CONF 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

[root@webserver1 nginx]# vim nginx.conf 
user nginx; 
worker_processes 1; 

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn; 
pid /var/run/nginx.pid; 


events { 
worker_connections 1024; 
} 


http { 
include /etc/nginx/mime.types; 
default_type application/octet-stream; 

log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" ' 
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" ' 
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"'; 

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main; 

sendfile on; 
#tcp_nopush on; 

keepalive_timeout 65; 

#gzip on; 

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

---

### WORKING HTTPS PROXY.CONF -- THIS WORKS

```
:[root@webserver1 nginx]# cd conf.d/ 
[root@webserver1 conf.d]# vim proxy.conf 

server { 
listen webserver1:443; 


ssl on; 
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/proxy.pem; 
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/proxy.key; 

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m; 
ssl_session_timeout 2m; 

location / { 
proxy_pass http://10.0.1.4:80; 
proxy_set_header Host $host; 
proxy_redirect off; 
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; 
} 
}
```

---

### NOT WORKING PROXY.CONF for HTTP access ONLY

```
server { 
listen 80 default_server; 
location / { 
proxy_pass http://10.0.1.4:80; 
} 
}
```

---

When it works i am hitting the URL : https://webserver1 or https://10.0.1.5

I am trying to get URL : http://webserver1 or http://10.0.1.5 to work.

Any help is appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two `server` blocks for this. Combine this with only one server block:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80 default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/proxy.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/proxy.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout 2m;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.1.4:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

I hope if this configuration was working with HTTPS, it would work with HTTP too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that before and it did not help. One more time, I just copy and pasted your solution content in the proxy.conf but the behavior is same from my windows machine which is on the same netowork. Oddly, http and https both works from the nginx reverse proxy linux machine itself. for example Curl https://  10.0.1.5 and curl http://  10.0.1.5 showed same output on machine 10.0.1.5 but URL http:// 10.0.1.5 does not work from browser on machine 10.0.0.133 which is in the same virtual network but in a separate subnet

Comment: Are you sure this is not a firewall problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this tool, I'm always manually tune my firewalls with `iptables` rules. Maybe it is a subject of another question with appropriate tags?

Comment: You are 100% right. I stopped firewalld on the nginx reverse proxy and my issue got resolved. thank you so much. now i will just add outbound allow in firewalld and i am good to go. I really appreciate your help i was really chasing in the wrong direction.